# GridLayoutManager spanSizeLookup bug

Tags: android, zxing, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am having an issue with `GridLayoutManger` `setSpanSizeLookup`, when an orientation of activity changes, I am changing the span count while checking if the specific position is some sort of type, this works perfectly on orientation change, my only problem is, I'm using `zxing` library to do barcode scanning, whenever a `button` is clicked I'm opening the `zxing` default intent and retrieve date from it, however when `zxing` is opening it goes to `landscape` and my current activity orientation is `portrait` this gives me the `IllegalArgumentException` that the layout manage throws when only opening the `Xzing` intent, the crash log is as this
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Item at position 0 requires 2 spans but GridLayoutManager has only 1 spans.`
this problem doesn't occur if i rotate the phone, only happens when I launch the `Xzing` intent, i couldn't really figure out how how I solve this issue as its bugging me. here is my `spanSizeLookup` -

```
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
     @Override
     public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return adapter.getHolders().get(position).getLabelHolder() != null ? getResources().getInteger(R.integer.span) : 1;
     }
});
```

the `span` is base on screen size so it can be 1-2, 2-3 and 3-4. i repeat this doesn't give me any error on orientation change, only the error occur when I open the `zxing`
P.S if i open `zxing intent` while my activity is on `landspace` the crash wont occur.

**Edit**

it seems like only launching the `zxing` default intent causing this issue, I'm having an `activity` where it goes `landscape` after it launches and the `exception` didn't occur, as a workaround i did, was that i created an `activity` that handles the `barcode` scanning with a delay of 1 second to launch the `intent` as if i didn't do that, it will throw the same `exception`.

**Edit 2**

I just found that, even without setSpanSpizeLookup the crash still occurs.  by just calling `manager.setSpanCount(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.span))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too late to answer this question, however in a latest project that i worked on, i faced the same issue & after some really debugging, i found out what was the cause to the issue but no clue why would it cause it.

`zxing` Library `intent` it actually calls `CLEAR_TOP` before calling the `startActivityForResult` & that was the problem, after modifying the source code of `zxing` `Intent` to remove that particular line, the crash is gone.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the source code that throws the exception in `GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk()`

```
final int spanSize = getSpanSize(recycler, state, pos);
if (spanSize > mSpanCount) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item at position " + pos + " requires " +
           spanSize + " spans but GridLayoutManager has only " + mSpanCount
           + " spans.");
}
```

Is your spanSize greater than your spanCount? Try to debug and probably change your spanCount and see how it works.

---- Updated ----

There're couple ways to switch between list and grid.

1. Only changing the spanCount.

   You have to call `LayoutManager.requestLayout()` after you change your spanCount. Otherwise your app may crash.
2. Only changing the SpanSizeLookUp.

   ```
   private class CustomSpanSize extends GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup {

     private static final int LIST_SPAN_SIZE = 1;
     private static final int GRID_SPAN_SIZE = 2;

     private int mSpanSize = LIST_SPAN_SIZE;

     public void asList() {
       mSpanSize = LIST_SPAN_SIZE;
     }

     public void asGrid() {
       mSpanSize = GRID_SPAN_SIZE;
     }

     @Override
     public int getSpanSize(int position) {
       return mSpanSize;
     }
   }
   ```

   and use it like that

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

     mCustomSpanSize = new CustomSpanSize();
     mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(mCustomSpanSize);
     RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
     recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

     ...
   }

   public void someFunction() {
     if (changed) {
       mCustomSpanSize.asList();
     } else {
       mCustomSpanSize.asGrid();
     }
     // use this to update the layout
     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     // or you can use this to update the layout
     mLayoutManager.requestLayout();
   }
   ```

   this way won't crash even you forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged` or `requestLayout`

Comment: hi Trey, thanks for the answer, if you read through my question, that exception never occur if i rotate the phone manually, however it happens when i lunch zxing intent which in turn make my current activity goes landscape and crashes, thats what confusing me, if i rotate it, it wont crash

Comment: hi k0sh, may I ask when your GridLayoutManager will has only 1 span.

Comment: when there is an item that is for example lets called it SEPARATOR

Comment: sorry for late response. could you post some sample code for me to debug? i need some code that will reproduce the crash.

Comment: hi Trey, its okay. here is a project i started yesterday, you could pull it and in Home class, line 115, remove manager.requestLayout()  and it will be crashing as well, i will try and make a simple project later as i am at work right now. https://github.com/k0shk0sh/KAM

Comment: It's nothing wrong about your sample code. You have to call `requestLayout` after you change your spanCount. especially when you try to change spanCount smaller.

Changing spanSize to switch between list and grid is another way. A safety way. It won't crash if you forget to `requestLayout`.  also you can call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the spanSize.

Comment: Thanks Trey to keep updating me on this,  i will check with tomorrow morning and update you back.

Comment: hi Trey, calling requestLayout followed by adapter.notifyDtaSetChanged() does not solve the issue. i guess its an internal bug in android, i can't even try block it to prevent the crash.

Comment: oh my bad. sorry to make you confused. What I mean is, for changing spanCount, you have to call requestLayout, but for changing spanSizeLookUp, you can call requestLayout or Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: you mean adding the request layout inside of the spansize lookup method? i have added below it on configuration change im calling requestLayout and also notifying adapter. that didn't do it . so frustrated about it :D .

Comment: Hello Trey, please check my answer if you have any clue why was it the cause. thanks for your help tho.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: call setSpanCount() and make it a bigger number than that span no?
Perhaps more code would be in order.

That sounds like it could have been a concurrent modification error. Try not using a delay per sé, but running modifications on the UI thread. This will block the UI from trying to access the list.

```
if(adapter.getHolders().get(position).getLabelHolder() != null)
    return getResources().getInteger(R.integer.column);
else 
    return 1;
```

so what is `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.column)`?

Isn't that going to be the same number every time?

Comment: getResources().getInteger(R.integer.column) depends on the orientation as i mentioned it can be 2,3,4 depending on which device size and which orientation the device is

Comment: ah, got it. slightly confusing attribute name.

Comment: kinda of, as im using that attr with different stuff, so instead of creating new attr that does the same im re-using it :p, im not really sure if i tried ur solution, however i will check it right away and update u

Comment: did you read the doc on that. It's not exactly obvious.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#setSpanCount(int)
...Because once you've turned the device columns have changed orientation. They're still columns. Clear as mud.

Comment: the orientation is always vertical for gridLayoutManager, the only thing that changes is the spanCount.

Comment: Try not overriding it. and just using the methods in the API first!

Comment: override what? im just setting the spanCount and the issue still occurs.

Comment: I think you're confused about which span you're referring to. the `GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup` class you extend is for determining span of each item, not of the entire structure.

Comment: Andy, lets get things together shall we? spanSizeLookup is meant to customize each row of the gridmanager and how would you determine if first row should display two or one, which setSpanCount is meant to determine how many spans per row should the gridmanager takes, if you read my second update which mention even without setspansizelookup the crash still occurs. i think i know what im doing

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, I had the same issue and just found the solution. After initializing the `GridLayoutManager` with the spanCount passed in the constructor, our app would crash. BUT, if I `setSpanCount()` after constructing the object, IT WORKS! :O

We're using RecyclerView 23.0.1. hope this helps someone.